# Как добавить или изменить файлы cookie в Safari 13?

Tags: браузер, safari

Каким образом можно добавить или изменить cookies в **Safari 13.1.2**

Пробовал традиционно, как и в Google Chrome добавить нужные мне cookies, вручную через инструменты разработчика, но не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

В Safari можно добавить cookies с помощью консоли разработчика.
Откройте консоль разработчика, и введите в неё следующий код, далее нажмите enter.

`document.cookie="nameCookie=valueCookie"`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).